Products Page Overlap issue (Fixed on Scroll) - Phone Specific Issue
On my Next.js website using shadcn-ui, products on the product page appear overlapped initially. However, scrolling down to the bottom and back up resolves the issue. This problem only occurs on two specific phones out of the PC and 7 phones I tested.
issue :

normal :

code for products page :
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "../ui/select";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import {
  ChevronLeft,
  ChevronRight,
  ChevronsLeft,
  ChevronsRight,
} from "lucide-react";
import ProductCard from "../custom/ProductCard";
import { productType } from "@/lib/types";

export default function ProductsPage({
  _products,
}: {
  _products: productType[];
}) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(_products);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [max, setMax] = useState(25);
  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(_products);
    changePage(0);
  }, [_products]);
  function changeOrder(order: "ATZP" | "ZTAP" | "ATZN" | "ZTAN") {
    switch (order) {
      case "ATZP":
        setProducts(
          products.toSorted((a, b) => (a.price ?? 0) - (b.price ?? 0))
        );
        break;
      case "ZTAP":
        setProducts(
          products.toSorted((a, b) => (b.price ?? 0) - (a.price ?? 0))
        );
        break;
      case "ATZN":
        setProducts(
          products.toSorted((a, b) => {
            let x = a.title.toLowerCase();
            let y = b.title.toLowerCase();
            if (x < y) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (x > y) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          })
        );
        break;
      case "ZTAN":
        setProducts(
          products.toSorted((a, b) => {
            let x = a.title.toLowerCase();
            let y = b.title.toLowerCase();
            if (x < y) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (x > y) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          })
        );
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  function changePage(page: number) {
    if (page != currentPage) {
      const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== 'undefined';
      if (isBrowser()){
        console.log("scrolling")
        window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:"instant"});
      }
      setCurrentPage(page);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex items-center p-5 pb-0 container">
        <Select onValueChange={changeOrder} dir="rtl">
          <SelectTrigger className="max-w-52">
            <SelectValue placeholder="ترتيب" />
          </SelectTrigger>
          <SelectContent>
            <SelectItem value="ATZP">السعر تصاعديا</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="ZTAP">السعر تنازليا</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="ATZN">الاسم تصاعديا</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="ZTAN">الاسم تنازليا</SelectItem>
          </SelectContent>
        </Select>
      </div>
      {products.length !== 0 ? (
        <div className="container flex items-stretch flex-wrap p-3 ">
          {products
            .slice(currentPage * max, currentPage * max + max)
            .map((product) => (
              <div
                key={product.id}
                className="p-2 xl:w-[calc(100%/5-.01px)] lg:w-[calc(100%/4-.01px)] md:w-[calc(100%/3-.01px)] w-[calc(100%/2-.01px)]"
              >
                <ProductCard product={product} />
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="w-full text-center text-xl font-medium px-2 py-5">
          لم يتم ايجاد اي منتج بهذا الاسم
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="flex gap-2 items-center justify-center pb-5">
        <Button
          variant={"ghost"}
          size={"icon"}
          disabled={currentPage == 0}
          onClick={() => {
            changePage(0);
          }}
        >
          <ChevronsRight className="w-5 h-5" />
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant={"ghost"}
          size={"icon"}
          disabled={currentPage == 0}
          onClick={() => {
            changePage(currentPage - 1);
          }}
        >
          <ChevronRight className="w-5 h-5" />
        </Button>

        {(() => {
          let pages: (number | null)[] = [];
          const pagesNum = Math.ceil(products.length / max);
          pages = [
            currentPage == pagesNum - 1 && pagesNum > 2
              ? currentPage - 2
              : null,
            currentPage > 0 ? currentPage - 1 : null,
            currentPage,
            currentPage < pagesNum - 1 ? currentPage + 1 : null,
            currentPage == 0 && pagesNum > 2 ? currentPage + 2 : null,
          ].filter((val) => val != null);
          return pages;
        })().map((val) => (
          <Button
            key={val! + 1}
            variant={val == currentPage ? "outline" : "ghost"}
            size={"icon"}
            className="text-base"
            onClick={() => {
              changePage(val!);
            }}
          >
            {val! + 1}
          </Button>
        ))}
        <Button
          variant={"ghost"}
          size={"icon"}
          disabled={currentPage == Math.ceil(products.length / max) - 1}
          onClick={() => {
            changePage(currentPage + 1);
          }}
        >
          <ChevronLeft className="w-5 h-5" />
        </Button>

        <Button
          variant={"ghost"}
          size={"icon"}
          disabled={currentPage == Math.ceil(products.length / max) - 1}
          onClick={() => {
            changePage(Math.ceil(products.length / max) - 1);
          }}
        >
          <ChevronsLeft className="w-5 h-5" />
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

code for product car :
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Check, CheckIcon, Plus, ShoppingBasket, ShoppingCart } from "lucide-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useData } from "../contexts/data-hook";

export default function ProductCard({
  product,
}: {
  product: {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    newPrice: number | null;
    mainImage: string;
  };
}) {
  const { addToCart, setCartOpen } = useData();
  let discount = 0;
  if (product.newPrice) {
    discount = Math.round(
      ((product.price - product.newPrice) / product.price) * 100
    );
  }
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Link
      href={`/product?id=${product.id}`}
      title={product.title}
      className="flex flex-col h-full relative"
    >
      {/* -------------------- image -------------------- */}

      <Image
        src={product.mainImage}
        alt={product.title}
        width={300}
        height={300}
        className="rounded w-full aspect-square"
        priority={true}
        placeholder="blur"
        blurDataURL="https://vtjclpwgljeqcdjmitvj.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/store/placeholder.png"
      />

      {/* -------------------- discount -------------------- */}

      {product.newPrice && (
        <div className="absolute bg-[#0094e9af] text-white font-sans leading-none pt-1.5 pb-1 px-2 rounded-ss rounded-ee font-medium">
          {discount}%
        </div>
      )}

      {/* -------------------- name -------------------- */}

      <p className="font-medium my-2 text-[#4D4D4D] line-clamp-1">
        {product.title}
      </p>

      {/* -------------------- prices and add to cart -------------------- */}

      <div className="flex justify-between items-start mb-2">
        {/* -------------------- prices -------------------- */}

        {product.newPrice ? (
          <div>
            <div>
              <p className="inline-block text-2xl font-medium">
                {product.newPrice.toLocaleString("en-us")}
              </p>
              <p className="inline-block ms-1 text-gray-600">ج.م</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p className="inline-block line-through text-gray-400 text-xl decoration-red-500 leading-none">
                {product.price.toLocaleString("en-us")}
              </p>
              <p className="inline-block ms-1 text-gray-400">ج.م</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p className="inline-block text-2xl font-medium">
              {product.price.toLocaleString("en-us")}
            </p>
            <p className="inline-block ms-1 text-gray-600">ج.م</p>
          </div>
        )}

        {/* -------------------- add to cart -------------------- */}

        <Button
          size={"icon"}
          type="button"
          className="text-2xl font-sans font-light"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
            addToCart({
              id: product.id,
              title: product.title,
              price: product.newPrice ?? product.price,
              image: product.mainImage,
              quantity: 1,
            });
            setLoading(true);
            setCartOpen(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
              setLoading(false);
            }, 2000);
          }}
          disabled={loading}
        >
          {loading ? <CheckIcon size={20} /> : <ShoppingCart size={20} />}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}

edit :
Interestingly, removing the button from the product card eliminates both the overlapping issue and a stuttering effect I was experiencing with the shadcn carousel.
